# Can I combine TextEdit files w/o copying and pasting?

Tags: macos, textedit

I’ve kept daily journal entries in Text Edit. Is there a way I can combine them into one file without cutting and pasting? I’m using TextEdit 1.1 on Mac OS El Capitan Version 10.11.6.

Answer (score 3):

Credit:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2242153?tstart=0

You can achieve this by opening terminal and typing `cd [path of the folder where your journals are located]` you should replace [ ] with the the folder where your diary entries are written , just drag and drop the folder into the terminal window.(Remember to hit space after typing `cd`) Then you can merge all the text edit files into one by typing 
`cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > file4` The file1.txt, file 2.txt and so on will be your diary entries so if you have more just type the name of the file followed by a space and the `>` symbol will merge all the documents into one file4.txt you can change the name as per your concern.

Comment: Yes indeed a good answer here and you can improve on this but joining all files together and then sorting the final output list in alphabetical order by using `cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > file4.txt && sort -u file4.txt -o file4.txt`

Answer (score 1):

By default, TextEdit creates Rich Text formatted files, e.g. filename.rtf, not Plain Text formatted files, e.g. filename.txt and as such, if the default is in play, then you cannot use `cat` as suggested in the other answers. This is because `cat` doesn't understand Rich Text formatting in order to concatenate the files.

If the documents are default TextEdit Rich Text formatted, then you'll need to use the `textutil` command:

```
textutil -cat rtf file1.rtf file2.rtf -output newfile.rtf
```

Answer (score 0):

Not from the TextEdit app but you can from the terminal. You can use the cat command and pipe file1 to a new file. Then use the cat command again on file2 and append to the new file. You may already know this but if not I can show you explicitly how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I don't know about the cat command. Can you tell me more about it or tell me where to find out? Thank you so much!

Comment: cat is a unix command that will print contents of a file. To do what you want you could do the following;  cat file1 > newfile then cat file2 >> newfile. This will combine fille1 and file2 into 1 newfile.

Comment: You can read the manual on most commands using the ‘man’ command. I.e. ‘man cat’